# Common ratio of a GP - $a_p, a_q, a_r$ given $a_1, a_2 ...$ form an AP

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, arithmetic-progressions, geometric-progressions

> Given $a_1, a_2 ...$ form an AP and $a_p, a_q, a_r$ form a GP. Find $\dfrac{a_q}{a_r}$

I did :

$$a_p, a_q, a_r \text{ form a GP}$$

$$\implies a_q^2 = a_p\cdot a_r$$

I got till here :

$$a(2q-p-r) = d(2q-p-r+pr-q^2)$$

**I cant eleminate a and d**. The answer given was in ratio of p,q,r or:

**Answer:** $\dfrac{r-q}{q-p}$

Thank you.

Comment: Hint: show that $a_k = a_1 + (k-1)(a_2-a_1)$ for all $k$, and make that substitution in your equation $a_q^2 = a_p a_r$.

Comment: @GregMartin That is already known isnt it? in AP, $a_n = a + (n-1) (a_2 - a_1)$ as $d=a_2 - a_1$. How will showing that help? actually, i used this only and simplified to get tho the current state. THank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since 
\begin{align*}
a_q^2 & = a_pa_r\\
a_q^2 -a_ra_q& = a_pa_r-a_ra_q\\
a_q(a_q-a_r)&=a_r(a_p-a_q)\\
\frac{a_q}{a_r}& =\frac{a_p-a_q}{a_q-a_r}\\
\frac{a_q}{a_r}& =\frac{d(p-q)}{d(q-r)}\\
\frac{a_q}{a_r}& =\frac{p-q}{q-r}\\
\end{align*}
My answer and yours doesn't match (they are close in form). Perhaps check your answer again. If you want the **common ratio** then it will be $\dfrac{a_r}{a_q}=\frac{q-r}{p-q}$.

Comment: how did you get the third step? directly? Thanks!

Comment: @TimKrul I have added another step (before the third step) to my solution. Hope that helps.

Comment: I still dont get how you got $\frac{d(p-q)}{d(q-r)}$ ? what is d?

Comment: @TimKrul Suppose $d$ is the common difference of the AP, then $a_p=a_1+(p-1)d$, $a_q=a_1+(q-1)d$. So $a_p-a_q=d(p-q)$.

Comment: oh! Thank you very much!